# shutdown.exe not invoked when system is locked

Tags: c#

I am just starting to learn C#. I am developing a small shutdown timer.

http://wshutdown.codeplex.com/

I am calling

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("shutdown", "/f")
```

when my count down timer reaches zero. This works fine and computer shutdowns properly. But when shutdown.exe is invoked when system is locked by user, shutdown is not triggered.
How can I trigger shutdown.exe when my computer is locked?

Comment: Yes Stephen Kennedy I tried that option too. Nothing happens until I unlock my PC. After unlocking, windows logs off in case I use /f or -f

Comment: Why down vote? can you explain?

Comment: Please show the code for your timer. Please include [which type of timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx) you are using. Also, could you check to see if `Process.Start` is being called but shutdown never runs or if `Process.Start` is never called at all, write a record to a file on the harddrive with a timesamp right before you call start should be good enough to check.