# Shutdown command is not working while system is locked

Tags: c#, windows

(There is a very similar topic that never got solved:[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26893222/shutdown-exe-not-invoked-when-system-is-locked))

Here is my **code**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
    Console.WriteLine("Hi");
    Process.Start("shutdown", "/s /t 0");
}
```

If I locked my system the shutdown process is not working otherwise it's working fine. When I unlock my system after 2 min it's showing only hi (5 times).

Comment: You could read `shutdown.exe`'s output to find the error it gives you, [or just call the proper API function yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24726116/when-using-exitwindowsex-logoff-works-but-shutdown-and-restart-do-not).

Comment: It's working fine when my system is active(not locked).

Comment: Did you try the /f (force) option?

Comment: down vote! Why? I searched for this problem in this forum found only one unresolved question. If I got the solution here it may help other.

Comment: Yes, tried /f. It's logging off the system not shutdown..

Answer (score 0):

I think the shutdown command requires elevated privilege, so whether you call it your way or use an API, I would expect a UAC prompt to be required.  You don't specify which version of Windows you're on but I think it's safe to assume UAC is present.

When the system is locked, a UAC prompt can't be shown and it times out after a while.  So without an interactive user's express permission your shutdown can't proceed.

I think, to achieve your aim, you'd need to create a windows service that runs with high privilege, and have it call the correct API to shut the machine down.  Then you can have a normal process communicate with your service and tell it to do the shutdown.

I hope somebody else can come up with a simpler solution for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If the problem is related to the permission, then why it's working while system is active(not locked)?

Comment: Yes, you make a fair point.  I guess you would have seen any UAC prompt when you run it while not locked.

Comment: I suspect this is still basically the right idea, it may be that shutdown is permitted if you have admin privilege *or* if you are running in the current interactive session - but in this case neither applies.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try other parameters of shutdown.exe like `/p` and/or `/f`?

Comment: /f = forcing applications to shutdown, not logging off

Comment: I understood. But In my case it's just logging off my system instead of force shutdown. I even tried in my colleague system.